# Limit this regex to 129 characters

Tags: regex

I have an email validation regex. I tried to limit it from 1 to 129 characters:

```
/(^([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\@([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\.([A-Za-z]{2,10})){1,129}$/
```

But in the end it does not work and allows you to enter as many characters as you like